# Python - Using pandas with reinforcement learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I would like to create in python some RL algorithm where the algorithm would interact with a very big DataFrame representing  stock prices. The algorithm would tell us: Knowing all of the prices and price changes in the market, what would be the best places to buy/sell (minimizing loss maximizing reward). It has to look at the entire DataFrame each step (or else it wouldn't have the entire information from the market).

Is it possible to build  such algorithm (which works relatively fast on a large df)? How should it be done? What should my environment look like and which algorithm (specifically) should I use for this type of RL and which reward system? Where should I start

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused with this .what I think you want to do is to check whether the stock prices of a particular company will go up or not or the stock price of which company will shoot up where you already have a dataset regarding the problem statement.

about RL it does not work on any dataset it's a technique that enables an agent to learn in an interactive environment by trial and error using feedback from its own actions and experiences.

you can check this blog for some explanation don't get confused.

https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-machine-learning-algorithms-you-should-know-953a08248861

Comment: I read this blog, yet I don't understand why shouldn't it work on pandas (or any dataset)? Also what I want to do is look at a specific company and pinpoint the best buying/selling points (I know you could look for min/max points but let's assume for the sake of the mission that we want to buy for long term and we're allowed to buy/sell only a fixed amount of times)